# Android 6.0 Marshmallow : Weird error with fragment animation

Tags: android, animation, android-6.0-marshmallow

One of my apps in the app store works perfectly fine with Android 5.0, but since today I have my device upgraded to 6.0 I get strange errors. I narrowed it down to the fragment transition animations.

```
ftrans.setCustomAnimations(inAnim, outAnim, inAnim, outAnim);
```

Without this line, my app also works fine on 6.0, with it I get this error :

```
10-14 14:36:51.016 23750-23820/? A/libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1, fault addr 0xb1 in tid 23820 (hwuiTask1)
10-14 14:36:51.118 200-200/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
10-14 14:36:51.118 200-200/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:6.0/MRA58K/2256973:user/release-keys'
10-14 14:36:51.118 200-200/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
10-14 14:36:51.118 200-200/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
10-14 14:36:51.118 200-200/? A/DEBUG: pid: 23750, tid: 23820, name: hwuiTask1  >>> com.xxx.xxx <<<
10-14 14:36:51.118 200-200/? A/DEBUG: signal 7 (SIGBUS), code 1 (BUS_ADRALN), fault addr 0xb1
10-14 14:36:51.110 200-200/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:54): avc: denied { search } for name="com.xxx.xxx" dev="mmcblk0p28" ino=1499496 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0:c512,c768 tclass=dir permissive=0
10-14 14:36:51.136 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000073  r1 96efeed8  r2 00000002  r3 00000005
10-14 14:36:51.136 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     r4 00000006  r5 00000073  r6 00000000  r7 96eff1e8
10-14 14:36:51.136 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     r8 00000005  r9 96efebd8  sl 96eff470  fp 00000016
10-14 14:36:51.136 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     ip 000000b1  sp 96efebd8  lr 00000006  pc b5d887d2  cpsr 300f0030
10-14 14:36:51.142 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 0005a7d2  /system/lib/libhwui.so
10-14 14:36:51.142 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0005b8a3  /system/lib/libhwui.so
10-14 14:36:51.142 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 00055e0b  /system/lib/libhwui.so
10-14 14:36:51.142 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0005c9fd  /system/lib/libhwui.so
10-14 14:36:51.142 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #04 pc 0001fd93  /system/lib/libhwui.so
10-14 14:36:51.142 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #05 pc 0001006d  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+112)
10-14 14:36:51.142 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 0005ecd3  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+70)
10-14 14:36:51.142 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0003f3e7  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
10-14 14:36:51.142 200-200/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00019b43  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
10-14 14:36:51.500 200-200/? W/debuggerd: type=1400 audit(0.0:55): avc: denied { read } for name="kgsl-3d0" dev="tmpfs" ino=5756 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:gpu_device:s0 tclass=chr_file permissive=0
10-14 14:36:52.189 799-25288/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.xxx.xxx/.MainActivity
10-14 14:36:52.190 200-200/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe
10-14 14:36:52.190 799-815/? I/BootReceiver: Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_01 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
10-14 14:36:52.257 799-901/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-14 14:36:52.286 799-4576/? D/GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 5
10-14 14:36:52.286 799-4576/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{d660a8a u0 com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.MainActivity}
10-14 14:36:52.321 799-808/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 71211(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 18(1032KB) LOS objects, 33% free, 32MB/48MB, paused 3.554ms total 114.532ms
10-14 14:36:52.372 214-214/? I/Zygote: Process 23750 exited due to signal (7)
10-14 14:36:52.379 799-1413/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.xxx.xxx (pid 23750) has died
10-14 14:36:52.386 799-1418/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 23069:com.android.documentsui/u0a35 (adj 15): empty #17
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator: Failed to dispatch window animation state change.
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator: android.os.DeadObjectException
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.onAnimationStopped(IWindow.java:534)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked(WindowAnimator.java:286)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked(WindowAnimator.java:678)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.-wrap0(WindowAnimator.java)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(WindowAnimator.java:123)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:856)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
10-14 14:36:52.864 799-817/? W/WindowAnimator:     at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
10-14 14:36:52.983 1889-2087/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
10-14 14:36:52.983 1889-2087/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
```

The "in" animation I use looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate">

<alpha
    android:fromAlpha="0" android:toAlpha="1"
    android:startOffset="@integer/fadein_offset"
    android:duration="@integer/fadein_duration"/>

<scale
    android:fromXScale="0%" android:toXScale="100%" android:fromYScale="0%" android:toYScale="100%"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:startOffset="@integer/fadein_offset"
    android:duration="@integer/fadein_duration"/>
```

The "out" animation looks identical, just reversed.

So my question is, what does this error mean and how do you do fragment transitions in marshmallow?

Edit : my addFragment method, where I use setCustomAnimations(). I added the SDK check as I use scale animations which are problematic on lower Android versions. Note however that this code works on Android <6, the animation runs fine and did so for 3 years.

```
private void addFragment(Fragment f, boolean addToBackstack, String tag) {
    FragmentManager fman = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ftrans = fman.beginTransaction();

//        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
//             ftrans.setCustomAnimations(inAnim, outAnim, inAnim, outAnim);
//        }

    if(addToBackstack) ftrans.addToBackStack(tag);
    ftrans.replace(R.id.content, f, tag);
    ftrans.commit();
}
```

On button press in fragment 1, I delegate to the activity via interface and there I call

```
@Override
public void showFacts(DBCategory category) {
    addFragment(FragFacts.Instance(category.id(), category.name()), true, FragFacts.TAG);
}
```

Edit 2 : 
I found out it's not animation in general, it's just the scale animation part of my transition which causes it. I took it out, now it works.

Comment: When do you call `ftrans.setCustomAnimations(inAnim, outAnim, inAnim, outAnim)`? [From Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#buildLayer()) Maybe the view is not attached to the window anymore?

Comment: I added the complete method, plus how I call it. I call it only on button press. As said, all of this works flawlessly in Android < 6.0...

Comment: I am also experiencing some stange issues with Android 6.0, with code that worked before.

Comment: Did you try, if `android.app.Fragment` behaves different from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`? Maybe it is a bug in the support library?

Comment: @AlbAtNf Didn't try that, but found out it's not animation in general, it's just the scale animation part of my transition which causes it. I took it out, now it works.

Comment: Maybe it is not even the whole scale animation part, only an attribute in that part? Any ways, good to hear you solved it.

Comment: It's still a mystery. Just tried another app, which has exactly the same animations, there everything works as expected. So it's probably not the animation. But then I don't know what is it... :)

Comment: I experienced the same thing. To add some more detail I am using v4 support fragments (ironically to fix graphics glitches with custom fragment animations). Using ObjectAnimator with rotationY anywhere near the fragment transition also crashes. Using fragmentTransaction.add() and hide() instead of replace() also did not help. The only non-solution I came up with was to use a plain vanilla fade in fade out transition.

Comment: This is a particularly difficult one.  I've had a similar problem off and on throughout development of my app (always only on my 6.0 device).  I tried several things based on what I read here.  Now I'm back with my original source (that had the problem) and now there's no problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is bug on Marshmallow when we do scale animation. For now we found a workaround by setting `view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE)`  [see documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE)

Comment: but it is not static

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a NullPointer exception masked as this because of Proguard obfuscation.
Run without Proguard and hopefully you'll see the underlying exception.

Comment: i can see it as "java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "J" field "mNativeHandle" in class "Lnet/sqlcipher/database/SQLiteDatabase;".
This is denoting to an aar file.Issue is i couldnt find a way to keep this file in proguard rules. any idea about how to add aar files in proguard?

Answer (score -1):

I got this exception and same problem `Failed to dispatch window animation state change.android.os.DeadObjectException`.

apparently this happened because i forgot to mention activity in manifest file. 
I was able to fix it by adding activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

simply added following with activity class name and solved the problem

example :

```
 <activity
        android:name="packageName.ClassName"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" 
        android:theme="@style/Theme.ActionBarSize_all_view">
    </activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, my app didn't crash but the transition between activities was buggy on >6.0. The reason was that one of the activities had the windowBackground property from its style set to @null. I commented it and it got fixed.

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">    
   <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
</style>
```