# Android - Fullscreen youtube Video using youtube oembed

Tags: android, webview, youtube

I 'm trying to embed a youtube video inside my template.
I 'm using VideoEnabledWebView, found here (https://github.com/cprcrack/VideoEnabledWebView) to enable full screen support.

While for Vimeo, this works perfectly (It even pauses the video, when you get out of the fullscreen), youtube loads its old flash player, and it evens stop my application when I m pressing full screen.

```
Failed to dispatch window animation state change.android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
                                                                      at android.view.IWindow$Stub$Proxy.onAnimationStopped(IWindow.java:534)
                                                                      at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateWindowsLocked(WindowAnimator.java:286)
                                                                      at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.animateLocked(WindowAnimator.java:678)
                                                                      at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.-wrap0(WindowAnimator.java)
                                                                      at com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator$1.doFrame(WindowAnimator.java:123)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:856)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                      at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                      at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                      at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
```

Any input will be kindly appreicated!

Thanks :)

Comment: Is your device Android M ,Seems like there is an issue with M http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128039/android-6-0-marshmallow-weird-error-with-fragment-animation

Comment: THanks for your comment. I think has to do with NestedScrollView + youtube flashPlayer, as the error occurs when I 'm trying to hide the NestedScrollView, when going fullscreen.